Broken jvm symlinks
I recently checked for broken symlinks on a Manjaro Linux system using # find / -xtype l -print, which revealed many broken symlinks pointing to inexistent files in /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/:
/usr/bin/jstack
/usr/bin/orbd
/usr/bin/xjc
/usr/bin/rmic
/usr/bin/jinfo
/usr/bin/jstat
/usr/bin/rmid
/usr/bin/javadoc
/usr/bin/schemagen
/usr/bin/jmap
/usr/bin/jps
/usr/bin/jstatd
/usr/bin/jarsigner
/usr/bin/unpack200
/usr/bin/jdb
/usr/bin/javah
/usr/bin/jar
/usr/bin/serialver
/usr/bin/servertool
/usr/bin/tnameserv
/usr/bin/javap
/usr/bin/wsgen
/usr/bin/pack200
/usr/bin/jconsole
/usr/bin/jcmd
/usr/bin/wsimport
/usr/bin/javac

Currently, I have jre21-openjdk set as the default, and jdk11-openjdk which came as part of the installation process for gephi v.0.10.1-2.
I'm not sure whether it's safe to remove them or not. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.
